# How should I set variables and nested data in UML diagrams?

Tags: oop, uml

I'm trying to set a UML from code with a bunch of nested data structures to view better the relationship and how I should to step to process this data.

I'm working in a Objects Diagram. How I should put a variable in a diagram like this? Are there a better way to set this "list inside a dict, inside a pd.DataFrame, inside a dict... and so on" code than with association (compositions, aggregations...)?

Python example:

```
x = 3
y = 'str'
z = [x, y]
a = [{b: ['d', 'f', {j: 'j', k: 'k'}], c: [[1, 2, 3],[4, 5, 6]]}, z, y]
```

My first attempt would be the next:
(Note: I added inside a parenthesis some values, but I know this is not correct, what should be the right way?)

[image]

I would like to see in one view al this data and clearly find the steps to process this.

Comment: Basically you don't have pure data structures in UML. You can use a class with just attributes, though.

Comment: Please show the diagram you made and your attempt to put a variable in the diagram and then we will tell you what you did good or wrong. That's how Stackoverflow works. By the way, please define "variable". Which programming language are you using?

Comment: Object diagram is static so variables are not interesting from this perspective. You have ways to show variables e.g. in activity diagram. But you have provided too little details t to be sure that's really what you wanted to show, thus I don't even feel this counts as an answer.

Comment: I added some details to the question, maybe now you can help me. The data structures that I have to process is too more complex than this. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

Your diagram is almost correct.
The composition relationship is not allowed between objects, only between classes. Objects have links. The value of an object can be specified as shown in the following diagram (incomplete).
See UML 2.5 specification, figure 9.28.

[image: objectdiagram]

Comment: Thanks www.admiraalit.nl, Do you have an idea of how to do it in Visual Paradigm? I have searched on the web and I don't find the options.

Comment: What would be "it"?

Comment: I don't know. I don't even know how to do it properly in my own tool; I just put separate transparant text labels "d" and "f" over the :String objects. :-)

Comment: Thomas, to write down the value of the variable in the box.

Answer (score 1):

You can model the value of object inside the Specification property of the InstanceSpecification

[image]